# Ros PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS error

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Error Message:

```
[ERROR] [1529093425.848827730]: Exception while loading planner 'ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner': Failed to load library /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libmoveit_ompl_planner_plugin.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = libmoveit_planning_interface.so.0.9.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
Available plugins: ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
```

I believe my macro matches my xml file:

Macro:

```
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(vs060A1_AV6_NNN_NNN_manipulator_kinematics::IKFastKinematicsPlugin, kinematics::KinematicsBase);
```

XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<library path="lib/libvs060A1_AV6_NNN_NNN_kinematics_lib">
  <class name="vs060A1_AV6_NNN_NNN_manipulator_kinematics/IKFastKinematicsPlugin" type="vs060A1_AV6_NNN_NNN_manipulator_kinematics::IKFastKinematicsPlugin" base_class_type="kinematics::KinematicsBase">
    <description>IKFast61 plugin for closed-form kinematics</description>
  </class>
</library>
```

I also find it very weird that it then lists it as an available plugin at the bottom of the error message.

Im on kinetic 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294255/ros-pluginlib_export_class-error/) by [av3006](https://answers.ros.org/users/35894/av3006/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> Exception while loading planner 'ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner': Failed to load library /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libmoveit_ompl_planner_plugin.so. [..]
> ```

The issue is not with the kinematics plugin you mention, but with MoveIt:

> ```
> Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = libmoveit_planning_interface.so.0.9.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
> ```

Please see #q294137 for some background.

In your case: did you perform any partial upgrades of your `.deb` packages or do you have MoveIt compiled from sources? If yes to either of those: do a full upgrade and/or recompile your workspace.

If you compiled the kinematics plugin from source: clean out your `devel` and `build` spaces and recompile. That is necessary in any case, but it probably won't influence the OMPL loading error.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1